# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I am displaying a dropdown menu of buttons on pug to display an HTML page. I'm using getElementsByClassName('dropdown-item') to get all the buttons in a HTMLCollection which is then iterated through to get a HTMLButtonElement. However, I am having difficulty receiving the value of the HTMLButtonElement in an alert box.

**PUG Code To render HTML elements**

```
    // Dropdown
    li.nav-item.dropdown
        button.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle.coursesbutt(data-toggle="dropdown") Courses
        .dropdown-menu
        button.dropdown-item(id='cc0' value='Default' onclick="changeFilter(this)") Reset Filter
        each coursename in coursecode
            button.dropdown-item(id=`${coursename}` value=`${coursename}` onclick="changeFilter(this)") #{coursename}
```

**Javascript to extract Button Elements**

```
    script.
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-item');
        for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ 
                alert(buttons[i].value); 
            })
        }
```

**Console Output**

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.
```

Comment: `buttons[i]` value is `undefined`

Comment: How will I get the value of each buttons when it is pressed using this method?

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(buttons)`

Comment: console.log(buttons) result is HTMLCollection(3) [button#cc0.dropdown-item, button#CZ4047.dropdown-item, button#CZ3003.dropdown-item, cc0: button#cc0.dropdown-item, CZ4047: button#CZ4047.dropdown-item, CZ3003: button#CZ3003.dropdown-item]

Comment: console.log(buttons[0]) gives <button class="dropdown-item" id="cc0" value="Default" onclick="changeFilter(this)">Reset Filter</button>

Comment: i can offer you a jquery solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery you can use `e.target.value`

https://jsfiddle.net/9y34tk2v/